# Extract embedded JPG from a RAW file w/ Python's MagickWand

Tags: python, magickwand, wand

I'd like to create thumbnails for RAW files, but processing the RAW file directly is very slow. I'd like to try to process the thumbnails from the embedded JPG first, and only render the RAW file as a last resort. How can I extract the embedded JPG using Wand?

Answer (score 0):

The `RAW` format varies between device and manufacture. Usually the complete image sensor data is stored as TIFF with a JPEG preview. Rather than loading the complete file into a tool, it may be quicker to find the spec, and extract the preview directly with `file` and `struct`. Here's an example with [Fujifilm's spec](http://libopenraw.freedesktop.org/wiki/Fuji_RAF/).

```py
 from struct import unpack

 fd = file('source.raf','rb')
 # Skip over header + directory
 # See manufacture specification
 offset  = 16 # Magic bytes
 offset += 12 # Version
 offset += 32 # Camera name
 offset += 24 # Directory start & meta
 fd.seek(offset, 0)
 jpeg_offest = unpack('i', fd.read(4)) # Read where JPEG data starts
 jpeg_length = unpack('i', fd.read(4)) # Read size of JPEG data
 fd.seek(jpeg_offset, 0)
 jpg_blob = fd.read(jpeg_length)
```

Now drop the blob into `wand`, or default back to RAW image

```py
 from wand.image import Image

 if jpeg_blob:
     img = Image(blob=jpg_blob)
 else:
     img = Image(filename='source.raf')
```

This solution will work if all your RAW data has been generated with the same manufacture spec. Else, you would need to build out file profiles for each spec, and evaluate the magic bytes of each RAW file to determine where the JPEG data is located. A flow may look something like...

[image: dot file]

Comment: Is it really reasonable to expect each manufacturer's raw format to have a constant offset to the thumbnail JPEG? And for it to never change as the format is updated?

Comment: It would not be, so there would be a need to read the [magic bytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Magic_numbers_in_files). Most manufacturers publish specs, and any solution should follow them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading Canon CR2 files, I've written a library called [`rawphoto`](https://github.com/photoshell/rawphoto) which you can use (it's also on [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rawphoto)).

To extract a thumbnail, you could do something like:

```
from rawphoto.raw import Raw
from wand.image import Image

with Raw(filename="example.CR2") as rawfile:
    blob = rawfile.fhandle.get_thumbnail()
// Do something with your JPEG thumbnail, eg. convert it to a PNG with Wand:
with Image(blob=blob) as image:
    image.format = 'png'
    image.save(filename='someimage.png')
```

I may add support for other raw formats later. Pull requests welcome.